# how to stop audio from playing when image has been touched

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have got an imageView that when the user taps the image audio starts playing, and this works great here are my code for that:

```
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Image7);
        imageView.setImageResource(mFullSizeIds[position]);
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Audio.this,mAudio[position]);  
    mp.start();
    return false;
   }
});
```

Now when I want the user to touch the image again the audio should stop.  So I have added this to my code:

```
if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) 
mp.stop();
return false;
          }
});
```

But now the sound doesn't even play.  Am really confused as logic tells me this should work.  What am I doing wrong here? Please help...

Not quite sure what you mean by block code?

Comment: Can you post the `OnTouchListener's` block of code?

Answer (score 1):

Did you call the function `prepare` or `prepareAsync` on your media?

Then, when stoping the media, I think that you must `reset` it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
mp.stop();
```

use

```
mp.pause();
```

Hopefully this remedies the problem. Otherwise, what needs to be done is you need to release the media player resources when you're done using it (if you intend on having it play back from the beginning each time they hit it. In that case, use

```
mp.release();
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
if (mp != null){
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
    }
```